# Get content of external div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a new problem. I wan't to get the content of a div from a external webpage. If I look in de page-source I see `<div id="content">...</div>`. How can I display the content with `document.write()`?

This question is written in really bad English, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What about displaying an external content in a iframe?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible, because modern browser block this so called cross-site-scripting.
It would be quite a security problem if every website could load your facebook page an read personal data.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

But there could be a solution using php's file_get_contents, depending on your situation
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's kind of the script doing the request for you, which I was talking about. - I had once a php script for getting a file via `header( 'Location: ' . $filename);`

Comment: I have to use javascript. I have found the answer by myself. I used simpely split for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#content').load('path/to/external_page.htm');
```

Not possible across domains without proper script which does the request for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to load external page to iframe 1x1 pixel and work with inner html.

Comment: It's still a problem. You cant read cross domain iFrame content.